# Can't figure out why Object reference is null

Tags: c#

Working on a program for class, and am about 95% complete, but have run into a roadblock. I've got a Flight class that holds information about the flight, as well as a seating chart. Using a windows form listbox to select from the flight objects I created by reading from a text file. I can get values for every property from the class object, except for one, SeatChart.

Here's the pertinent code in the main program:

```
    private void lstFlights_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        curFlight = (Flight)lstFlights.SelectedItem;
        DisplayNewFlightChart();
    }

    private void DisplayNewFlightChart()
    {

        int seats = curFlight.Rows * curFlight.Seats;
        lstSeatingChart.Items.Clear();
        string[] seatChart = curFlight.SeatChart;
        for (int x = 0; x <= seats; x++)
        {
            lstSeatingChart.Items.Add("Seat " + (x + 1) + " " + seatChart[x]);
        }
    }
```

And here is the code from the class:

```
class Flight
{
    private string mPlane;
    private string mDepartureTime;
    private string mDestination;
    private int mRows;
    private int mSeats;
    private string[] mSeatChart;

    public Flight()
    {
    }

    // Create the overloaded Constructor
    public Flight(string planeType, string departureTime,
                  string destination, int numRows,
                  int numSeatsPerRow)
    {
        this.Plane = planeType;
        this.DepartureTime = departureTime;
        this.Destination = destination;
        this.Rows = numRows;
        this.Seats = numSeatsPerRow;
        this.SeatChart = mSeatChart;


        mSeatChart = new string[Rows * Seats];

        for (int seat = 0; seat <= mSeatChart.GetUpperBound(0); seat++)
        {
            mSeatChart[seat] = "Open";
        }



    }

    public string Plane
    {
        get { return mPlane; }
        set { mPlane = value; }
    }

    public string DepartureTime
    {
        get { return mDepartureTime; }
        set { mDepartureTime = value; }
    }

    public string Destination
    {
        get { return mDestination; }
        set { mDestination = value; }
    }

    public int Rows
    {
        get { return mRows; }
        set { mRows = value; }
    }

    public int Seats
    {
        get { return mSeats; }
        set { mSeats = value; }
    }

    public string[] SeatChart
    {
        get { return mSeatChart; }
        set { mSeatChart = value; }
    }

    public void MakeReservation(string passName, int seat)
    {
        bool seatTaken = false;
        if (mSeatChart[seat] != "Open") seatTaken = true;

        if (passName != "" && seatTaken == false)
        {
            mSeatChart[seat] = passName;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a Passenger Name, in an unreserved seat");
        }

    }
```

It's telling me the curFlight.SeatChart is null, even though I can pull .Rows and .Seats from the curFlight just fine. I have no clue why .SeatChart is messing up. lstFlights is the list of flight objects pulled from the text file, and lstSeatingChart is where I want to display a list of seats.

Comment: I sincerely hope this is not a production code. add this to the `public Flight(){ this.mSeatChart = new string[1]; }`

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace?

Comment: Object Reference not set to an instance of an object

System.NullReferenceException
  at WindowsFOrmasAPplication3.Reservations.DisplayNewFlightCHart() in 
d:\users\nathan\desktop\c#
Projects\program4\windowsformsappliocation3\Form1.cs:line 76

Comment: @Ozmethod: no that's the exception, a stacktrace is a stack of where the exception originates from....

Comment: Apologies, very new programmer here. I'm uncertain how to provide the stacktrace. I will google it, unless you can explain in a short time frame

Comment: Adding that line eliminates the exception, but doesn't really solve the problem. Now it just shows the 1 seat no matter which flight I select, instead of the 6 seats for the first flight, or 12 seats for the second.

Comment: @Ozmethod: Google images for "c# stacktrace what it looks like".  You need to provide us that so that we can see the exact error, line number where it occurred, etc.

Comment: Ok, so you want this:

  WindowsFormsApplication3.exe!WindowsFormsApplication3.Reservations.DisplayNewFlightChart() Line 76 C#
> WindowsFormsApplication3.exe!WindowsFormsApplication3.Reservations.lstFlights_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e) Line 65 C#
  [External Code] 
  WindowsFormsApplication3.exe!WindowsFormsApplication3.Program.Main() Line 19 C#
  [External Code]

Answer (score 3):

You are setting SeatChart to mSeatChart, which is null at that time. So no reference to an object is made for this.SeatChart.

After that you initialize mSeatChart and fill it.

You should move setting this.SeatChart after initializing mSeatChart.

```
mSeatChart = new string[Rows * Seats];
this.SeatChart = mSeatChart;
```

Edit:
In addition, SeatChart is the property and mSeatChart is the member variable. SeatChart will be used to expose mSeatChart, so it's really weird to set SeatChart with mSeatChart. So weird that I didn't even think you were doing that.
So in your case leave the following out in the constructor:

```
this.SeatChart = mSeatChart;
```

I think the actual cause of your issue is somewhere else in the code, where you initiate Flight and fill the list. If I understand correctly you get a null reference error on the concatenation in the for loop?

```
    string[] seatChart = curFlight.SeatChart;
    for (int x = 0; x <= seats; x++)
    {
        lstSeatingChart.Items.Add("Seat " + (x + 1) + " " + seatChart[x]);
    }
```

Check where you initate each Flight object. I bet you are using the empty constructor: new Flight()
Remove the empty constructor, because you don't expect empty values apparently. And if you really need the empty constructor then either initiate all member variables as expected or perform a null check wherever you want to use them.

And once you found the cause, make sure you change the for loop to

```
    for (int x = 0; x < seats; x++)
```

since you are checking for the number of seats and do a zero-based loop. If x = seats you would have performed the loop seats + 1 times (rows*seats + 1).

Comment: either this or, like @zaitsman mentioned, add the seat chart initialization into the default constructor

Comment: Since SeatChart has to have a number of items equal to Rows * Seats initializing first to string[1] won't help: the OP won't get a null reference anymore but will get the wrong string array with 1 element.

Comment: @Dacker3 did some testing and you are right. I think the best way is to not touch this.SeatChart at all in the constructor, since the property makes the field available anyways

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what happened. No error anymore, but now I'm just getting 1 seat instead of the result of seats*rows. Obviously I've got an error somewhere else as well

Answer (score 0):

If your code relies on a particular property never being null, you need to make sure it is initialized in all constructors.

Based on the logic of your class, I would suggest you shouldn't have a parameter less constructor. It doesn't make sense to have a flight that didn't have a known number of seats (in your implementation at least).

Also some style things.

You don't need to declare your private instance variables. Just use

```
    public string destination {get; set;}
```

Declare "open" as a class constant and use that constant rather than the hard coded string value.

Comment: Thanks for the style tips, I will take note of them.